# How to send a POST request to an HTTP2 with Hyper

Tags: python, request, http2, hyper

I just want to send a post request to submit a form to a website who only use h2 protocol.

```
import requests
from hyper.contrib import HTTP20Adapter
import hyper

session = requests.session()

session.mount(url, HTTP20Adapter())

r = session.post(url, data=payload, headers=header)


print(r.text)
```

This doesn't seem to work. And since Hyper documentation is pretty empty. I needed some external help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have neither supplied enough code that allows to reproduce the problem nor given a proper error description.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug in `hyper` library (tested with `Release v0.7.0.`). I have the same problem with raw `hyper` library and I had to set `Content-Length` query header. Without this header `hyper` HTTP/2 do not send query body. With HTTP/1.1 it works as expected without setting `Content-Length` header.

It was reported as bug:
https://github.com/Lukasa/hyper/issues/320